# $\sigma\mathcal C$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal C$. Show $\sigma\mathcal C\subset\sigma\mathcal D$ if $\mathcal C\subset\mathcal D$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$ are two collections of subsets of $E$. How do I prove the following:

$$\mathcal{C}\subset\mathcal{D}\implies\sigma\mathcal{C}\subset\sigma\mathcal{D}?$$

Comment: What is $\sigma C$?

Comment: Is $\sigma C$ the sigma-algebra generated by $C$? What do you find confusing? (It is very easy to write a proof, but if you find this confusing, then I doubt that reading the proof will be useful or clarify your difficulties.)

Comment: $\sigma\mathcal{C}$ is the sigma-algebra generated by $\mathcal{C}$. I need a clear proof to get started (I'm not a set theorist nor a mathematician, just trying to learn the basics).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use the fact that $\sigma\mathcal{A}$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $\mathcal{A}$. If you know this fact then you can derive the desired result in a few easy steps:

- $\sigma\mathcal{D}$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $\mathcal{D}$;
- $\mathcal{C}$ is contained in $\mathcal{D}$;
- $\sigma\mathcal{D}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra containing $\mathcal{C}$;
- $\sigma\mathcal{C}$ is the . . .
- Therefore $\sigma\mathcal{C}$ is contained in $\sigma\mathcal{D}$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: $\sigma\mathscr{C}$ is the intersection of all $\sigma$-algebras $\mathscr{A}\subseteq\wp(E)$ such that $\mathscr{C}\subseteq\mathscr{A}$; see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma-algebra#.CF.83-algebra_generated_by_a_family_of_sets) if this fact is not already familiar. If $\mathscr{D}\subseteq\mathscr{A}$, then certainly $\mathscr{C}\subseteq\mathscr{A}$.